React preventDefault function doesn't stop reloading the form page
I am creating a React context to decode jwts and manage login function of the users. Backend is written using django.
These are simplified code.
The issue I am facing here is that I am unable to get the data from the login form because the preventDefault() in the loginUser function doesn't work and makes the login form refresh each and every time I submit the form. The login form url becomes "http://localhost:5173/employee/login + login?email=c%40c.com&password=c&submit=Log+in".
Is there any other way for me to not reload the login form page and successfully get the data to AuthContext page?
OnClick fucntion can't be used on the button because of the way I wrote the code. And I am unable to think another way to acheive this.

I tested the 2 pages you shared, and it seems like you got it right.
Just doing e.preventDefault() does stop the reloading, so I have a guess as to why this could be happening. You said you're using Django as your backend, so it is possible that the response you're returning is making the browser reload the page.
As far as I know, if you're returning a JsonResponse with some status code you should be fine
In Here you can comment and un-comment the e.preventDefault() line and you'll notice that as long as it's un-commented the page does not reload
